# Bootstrap - small spacing on end of last column in row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to make a row with multiple columns (col-xs-3,col-xs-3,col-xs-3,col-xs-2,col-xs-1), but then I realized that its total width is a little shorter than regular col-xs-12. In snippet in looks fine, but on my page it doesn't. Does anybody know how to fix it?

[image]

```css
.cYellow{
  background-color:#FF0;
}
.cBlue{
  background-color:#00F;
  border:solid 1px black;
}
.cRed{
  background-color:#F00;
  border:solid 1px black;
}
.cGreen{
  background-color:#0F0;
  border:solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row cYellow">
    <div class="col-xs-12 cBlue">a</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row cYellow">
    <div class="col-xs-6 cRed">a</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 cGreen">a</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row cYellow">
    <div class="col-xs-3 cRed">a</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 cGreen">a</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 cRed">a</div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 cGreen">a</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 cRed">a</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you can't reproduce it in a JSFiddle or Stack Snipper it's going to be hard to offer any advice. On this occasion a link to the page with the issue might be the only way.

Comment: Better if you could create a **SIMILAR [demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net)**, or share your live link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here resides in browser's approximation of fractional values  expressed in pixel as result of a percentage rule.

Bootstrap uses percentages for column widths: since  a single pixel cannot be divided on the screen the sum of many rounded value might result lower compared to a single full width element.

In your case the sum of percentages is 100% but the computed width of the elements may vary depending on container and viewport size, due to approximation on periodic percentages, in fact:

```
.col-xs-1{
   width:8.33333333%
}
```

results in a computed width of 48.828px inside a md container (970px wide).

### Solution: float last element to the right

Add the `.pull-right` class to your last column to force it to align to the right edge of your container.

Alternatively you can specify a class for the row (eg. `.my-row` ) and float its last child via css

```
.my-row :last-child{
   float:right;
}
```

In this way the rounding is distributed among columns resulting less evident.

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/h7983qmt/